# How to reveal a command's script?

Tags: info

For now, the solution I got is to use, for example, `whereis [command]` and then `cat` into the file to see the script.

But is there any other command to be able to directly see a command's execution script without having to find the binary file?

Comment: A binary is not a script. If you look at a binary with `cat`, you will mess up your shell. Use `less` instead.

Comment: `more $(command -v mycommand)` ? beware that if command is not a shell result will mess up your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all commands have "scripts".

Some, like `cd`, `export`, `set` are built into your parent shell.

Some are aliases, which can be anything, including complex commands.

Some are ELF format files (binaries, programs), which are loaded into memory (by `ld.so`) and executed.

Some are "scripts".

The `file` command will help you. Read `man file`.